# Relation between out of order command queue and blocking and non-blocking OpenCL Write

Tags: opencl, gpu, nvidia, amd-processor

I am trying to figure out the relationship between the `clcreatecommandqueue` and `clenqueuewritebuffer` API.

I am using a very simple example i.e. Vector addition and AMD CodeCL to gauge the performance.

Here are some numbers with different configurations for clcreatecommandqueue and clenqueuewritebuffer API:

```
Scenario      Command-Queue Properties      blocking_write       time taken

1             in-order                      non-blocking         46.83ms

2             in-order                      blocking             4.711ms

3             out-of-order                  non-blocking         46.55ms

4             out-of-order                  blocking             4.358ms
```

The recorded time taken is for 4MB data transfer from cpu-to-gpu (I got similar results for a 40MB data transfer).

From my understanding, the least time taken should be for out-of-order and non-blocking and the most time taken should be for in-order and blocking write.

But the above data shows that whatever the type of command queue, the blocking write outperforms everything else.

Can anybody help me out in understanding these stats?

Comment: How are you timing these? I've just tried the same experiment with a solitary data transfer on a mix of AMD and NVIDIA GPUs, and got almost identical timings for each configuration. This is exactly what I would expect, since the performance gains from using asynchronous data transfers and out-of-order queues come from overlapping these commands with other host or device side computation.

Comment: These results I got on AMD A10-6800 APU using AMD's CodeXL profiler. 
Do you have any thoughts why I am getting this 10 times timing difference by setting different configuration(and that too blocking non-asynchronous mode).

Comment: Do they actually look like they are taking that long on the timeline or are there empty gaps? I've seem APP Profiler (the predecessor to CodeXL) say transfers are taking only a short time, but there are gaps on the timeline, indicating they really were longer.